# Vim - count lines in selected range

Tags: vim

I want to count lines in a range, not matter what range, but let it be, say, a visual block.
What is the shortest way to do it. All that comes to my mind is something like: `'<,'>s/.//n`
but I don't believe it is the shortest way.

So, can somebody give me a hint?

Answer (score 179, accepted):

In visual mode, press <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>C-g</kbd>

Typical output:

> `Selected 7 of 22 Lines; 8 of 32 Words; 201 of 491 Chars; 201 of 497 Bytes-- VISUAL LINE --`

---

**Source**: **[`:he count-items`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/tips.html#count-items)** (*discoverable as: `:he`<kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>...*)

Comment: Great! Thank you for this tip, as soon as 10 minute will pass, I'll mark this as an answer ) But it interesting, nevertheless, is there a function in vim. I'm pretty sure there should be a function.

Comment: @shabunc: what do you mean "is there a function in vim"? Do you mean something you can `:call`? Your question didn't mention that.

Comment: function just in sense like other built-in functions (`:h functions` ;)

Comment: @shabunc So, "yes", then. You didn't mention you wanted a function in your question. I don't believe a built-in function exists to count the number of lines in a range, but you could define your own pretty easily with two calls to `getpos()` (which can accept a mark as input and returns the position, including line number) and a bit of subtraction.

Comment: @shabunc: The closest I can find is **[`:perl $curbuf->Count` (returns the number of lines)](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/if_perl.html#perl-Count)**

Answer (score 27):

Set the option `showcmd` (`:h 'sc'`), and you will never ever need to type anything to know how many lines are selected -- at first, as I forget that I've set this option, I didn't understand the point of your question. ^^'

Otherwise, if you want to obtain that number programmatically, it's simply:

```
:echo line("'>") - line("'<") + 1
```

From within a range-function, it can also be obtained by `a:lastline-a:firstline+1`. (`:h function-range-example`)

Comment: this is the simplest solution IMHO: just add `set showcmd` to your `.vimrc`, and the number of selected lines will always be shown at the bottom.

Answer (score 13):

`'<,'>s///n` is one character shorter. :-)

If I just want to know the number of lines in a visual selection I usually just yank it (hit `y`). It'll say "5 lines yanked" or "block of 5 lines yanked" depending on the type of selection.

Comment: me also usually yanking for that purpose. And today I suddenly realized that it is a time to lear something new )))

Comment: This answer is probably the best; on my terminal, `g C-g` will only display for a fraction of a second and need at least 5-6 tries to catch a glimpse of the output...